# How to return Json data array with PHP/Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I'm devoloping an api with Laravel and I have to get the data of a json file in a url, this is my code:

```
public function index(){
    $json_file=file_get_contents("url that I'm using");
    $json_str = json_decode($json_file);
    
    echo $json_str;
}
```

The JSON file:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "clients": [
      [
       "name": "Tyler Durden",
       "job": "leader of the ..."
      ],
  ]
}
```

But when I access my route that call the index() I get this error:

`Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string`

I want to get any pair of clients and save them, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't print an object using `echo`, to print an object you can use

```
print_r($json_str);
var_dump($json_str);
```

In your case you just need a `return` statement

```
return $json_str;
```

In Laravel you can also, do this

```
return response()->json($json_str);
```

Comment: The "return $json_str" has worked, but how can I print the "clients" values now?

Comment: You can access them by doing  `return $json_str['clients'];` if that what you mean.

Comment: It doesn't work, but I had used ```return $json_str->clients[0];``` and that and served me

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to print a json instead of a string. echo will only print a string.

Answer (score 0):

return response($json_str); or return response()->json($json_str); with Status Code
return response()->json(['data'=>$json_str],200);

Comment: Thanks, man. But now I'm trying to get the values the pair of "clients" data, any hint?